# (almost) All text becomes blank except in some apps

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10

From time to time, text will become blank in some parts of the system, such as Windows Explorer and other important apps. Even non-system programs will have problems displaying text.

The only fix is a restart, and in some cases multiple restarts are required before text starts to appear again.

The bug doesn't seem to affect UWP apps, or custom-drawn applications (e.g.: Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

After opening the Fonts folder in the explorer and noticing only 8 "basic" fonts were being displayed (some fixedsys and terminal raster fonts), though all the files were physically there (as confirmed by a quick `dir` in the folder), I had the idea of checking the `desktop.ini` file. This is the file that tells Windows, "this is a special folder, it's the Fonts folder, treat it and display it accordingly". To my surprise, it only contained the first line and not the second one, so obviously Windows had trouble parsing it and thought the Fonts folder was missing.

The simple fix is to modify the C:\Windows\Fonts\desktop.ini file so that it has the following content:

```
[.ShellClassInfo] 
UICLSID={BD84B380-8CA2-1069-AB1D-08000948F534}
```

Note that only new (not already running) applications are completely affected by the bug, so if you've got a spare notepad window you can use it to edit the file.

Comment: Some explanation would be helpful.

Comment: @harrymc added explanation